# Python CSV module, add column to the side, not the bottom

Tags: python, csv

I am new in python, and I need some help. I made a python script that takes two columns from a file and copies them into a "new file". However, every now and then I need to add columns to the "new file". I need to add the columns on the side, not the bottom. My script adds them to the bottom. Someone suggested using CSV, and I read about it, but I can't make it in a way that it adds the new column to the side of the previous columns. Any help is highly appreciated.

Here is the code that I wrote:

```
import sys
import re

filetoread = sys.argv[1]
filetowrite = sys.argv[2]

newfile = str(filetowrite) + ".txt"

openold = open(filetoread,"r")
opennew = open(newfile,"a")

rline = openold.readlines()

number = int(len(rline))
start = 0

for i in range (len(rline)) :
    if "2theta" in rline[i] :
        start = i

for line in rline[start + 1 : number] :
    words = line.split()
    word1 = words[1]
    word2 = words[2]
    opennew.write (word1 + " " + word2 + "\n")

openold.close()
opennew.close()
```

Here is the second code I wrote, using CSV:

```
import sys
import re
import csv

filetoread = sys.argv[1]
filetowrite = sys.argv[2]

newfile = str(filetowrite) + ".txt"

openold = open(filetoread,"r")

rline = openold.readlines()

number = int(len(rline))
start = 0

for i in range (len(rline)) :
    if "2theta" in rline[i] :
        start = i

words1 = []
words2 = []

for line in rline[start + 1 : number] :
    words = line.split()
    word1 = words[1]
    word2 = words[2]
    words1.append([word1])
    words2.append([word2])

with open(newfile, 'wb') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter= "\n")
    writer.writerow(words1)
    writer.writerow(words2)
```

These are some samples of input files:

- https://dl.dropbox.com/u/63216126/file5.txt
- https://dl.dropbox.com/u/63216126/file6.txt

My first script works "almost" great, except that it writes the new columns at the bottom and I need them at side of the previous columns.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to use `writerow` is to give it a single list that contains the data for *all* the columns.

```
words.append(word1)
words.append(word2)
writer.writerow(words)
```

Comment: I change the words you suggested, but still does not work. All I need is that the new pair of columns I want to add, being added to the side of the columns that are already in the (output) file. I am seriously lost with this.

Comment: @henrymartinez, since your original code doesn't appear to attempt to add any columns I'm at a loss as to where your misunderstanding lies.

Comment: Thanks Mark for the reply. I am new with python and very likely what I do is not correct. My first code take to columns from a file wich contains many columns (see samples of the input file at the top) and then copy them in a "new file". I just want that when I copy a new set of columns in the same "new file", this columns would be added  next to the previous ones, not at the bottom. Any suggestion in how should I write my code is highly appreciated. Best regards.